# When implementing your own IUserStore, are the "optional" interfaces on the class actually optional?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm working with Microsoft's Asp.Net Identity framework version 2, and am implementing my own IUserStore. My new class `MyUserStore` implements the `IUserStore<MyUserClass,int>` interface and the `IUserPasswordStore<MyUserClass,int>`, which is what is required to use it with the `UserManager<MyUserClass,int>` class. Or at least that's what I gathered from reading tutorials like [this](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx):

> "The one required interface in the identity system is IUserStore" - Scott Allen

But this doesn't seem to be the case when I run the code.

I initialize my manager:

```
var uMan= new UserManager<MyUserClass, int>(new MyUserStore()); 
var sMan = new SignInManager<MyUserClass, int>(uMan,authCtxFromOwin);
```

And when sMan.PasswordSignIn(...) on the SignInManager is executed, no matter what, the SignInManager always runs functionality in the UserManager that depends on the optional interfaces. Here's the source for the PasswordSignInAsync method from the SignInManager class:

```
public virtual async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
        {
           ...
            if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id).WithCurrentCulture())
            {
                return SignInStatus.LockedOut;
            }
            if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password).WithCurrentCulture())
            {
                return await SignInOrTwoFactor(user, isPersistent).WithCurrentCulture();
            }
            ...
            return SignInStatus.Failure;
        }
```

It always calls UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync() before it tries to check the password, so if the store doesn't implement the IUserLockoutStore interface, an exception gets thrown every time no matter what.

Does this mean that to use the default functionality of the UserManager and SignInManager classes, you need to implement every I*Store interface?

It looks the the workaround is to inherit from SignInManager and override the PasswordSignInAsync method. Is that the standard practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the latest version of the source on GitHub, this is been fixed (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c9d27e27e6dd6c15b4228de6e5de3c1a22c15a6d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L94). Obviously this doesn't help for the current releases but we should see this in the future.

Comment: Thanks @AntSwift! I've been stuck on that for some time!

Comment: Well actually it doesn't work: I've overridden SupportsUserLockout on my UserManager but it isn't called and still throws the annoying "Store does not implement IUserLockoutStore<TUser>." This is very frustrating. Not only it's inner working is very confusing, but it simply does not work. But that's Microsoft I guess.

Answer (score 8):

What I found that Identity framework is not consistent with "optionality" of required I*Store. In some public methods it checks if the required Store is provided, in some other places it just calls for the method. I have not figured out which ones are absolutely required and which ones can be not called. So I'd go with the exception trail and implement whatever the stores are required for your application.

Comment: It looks like they tried to get away from Membership situation, where you had single interface with hundred method to implement, but not successfully - they split everything to smaller interfaces, but in the result you still have huge UserStore class.

Comment: I don't think there were any interfaces in MembershipProvider. `UserStore` class is implementation detail of their own. You can have many small classes if you are making implementation yourself.

Comment: You're right regarding MembershipProvider, it was not an interface, but abstract class, in current context I don't think that matters much, as you had to implement everything there and here. Regarding UserStore - I'm making it by myself as small as possible (just to be able to use SignInManager), without including anything I don't need and it still contains 19 methods already, I guess that is bare minimum at the moment.

Comment: Yeah its optional in the sense that if you dont do anything that tries to call them then you dont need to implement it :).