# Asp.Net Identity Store does not implement IUserEmailStore<TUser>

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I am exploring this identity framework and while implementing Custome UserStore, Is there anyway to get rid of these, so called optional interfaces. 
As per this thread, doesn't look like an option. [When implementing your own IUserStore, are the "optional" interfaces on the class actually optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703776/when-implementing-your-own-iuserstore-are-the-optional-interfaces-on-the-clas)

i am using 2.2.1 version on .Net Framework 4.5 MVC5

Answer (score 1):

So I looked into Asp.Net.Identity assembly code, and here is my understanding. Chances are, this may be obvious to you, but still sharing:

For calling **CreateAsync** on **UserManager**, by default, I have to implement these store Interface: *IUserStore,IUserPasswordStore, IUserSecurityStampStore,IUserEmailStore,IUserLockoutStore*. Most of calls to these methods has been templated in UserManager.

**Good news is**, most of **UserStore** calls to these interface method has a condition before call, which we can set in **UserManager**.

For example: *Set "RequireUniqueEmail=false" in UserManager and there will be no call to IUserEmailStore.GetEmailAsync while calling CreateAsync, and you don't have to implement it on your UserStore.*

I have create map for **CreateAsync** which I think should be helpful.

[image]

> So, to answer original question, if we know what we are going to
>   Validate(conditions), we can implement only those interfaces on UserStore.